# Link arrow design in Rappid (JointJS?)

Tags: javascript, svg, jointjs, rappid

I'm using Rappid to develop a chart, and I need to modify the default arrows to look like the 1st and 3rd ones in this picture ("One" and "One (and only one)"):

[image]

The best I can get gives me this though:

[image]

There is either empty space or the lines are too close to the end... I'll admit I've researched SVG d-paths heavily and I still barely understand them. These are the two I'm using:

`M56 0 L56 16 L54 16 L46 16 L46 0 L48 0 L48 16 L54 16 L54 0`

`M56 0 L56 16 L54 16 L24 16 L54 16 L54 0`

Answer (score 1):

The link arrows are automatically translated and auto-oriented by JointJS (`joint.dia.linkView`). It makes sure the line always starts/ends at the arrow boundary i.e. You can not force the line to go through the arrow.

You can trick this by adding the missing line segment to the arrow path itself.

```
'M 0 -10 L0 10 M 0 0 L-10 0'
```

[image: See the red arrow.]

The other option is to use `SVGMarker` instead. Please see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/rghohwhf/) demo including also a workaround for IE bug.